# Problemas creando un consecutivo en ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

Deseo crear  cuatro tipos de consecutivos para cuatro tablas diferentes, cada consecutivo se debe incrementar cada vez que se crear un nuevo resgitro.
Los tipos de consecutivos son:

1. CR-0000000
2. CI-GCP-22-000 (CI-> no cambia/ GCP --> tiene 12 valores diferentes / 22 --> año  / 000 --> el consecutivo).
3. CE-ENE-22-00  (CE -> no cambia / ENE --> tiene 4 valores diferentes / 22 año / 000 -> consecutivo)

Entonces la forma qué e encontrado, es tener dos celdas para el 1° consecutivo, una celda "numero_consecutivo" en formato texto para que quede "00000001" y la celda "consecutivo" que es campo calculado "CR"+"-"+[NUMERO_CONSECUTIVO].

Entonces para el primer consecutivo, en el formulario de ingreso de datos tengo al darle click al input de número_consecutivo:

'Quiero obtener el útlimo valor de la tabla, convertirlo a entero y sumarlo
=Cint(DUltimo("NUMERO_CONSECUTIVO"; "FAC_FACTURA")) + 1

'Pero tengo un error.

¿Cuál sería la mejor solución para este problema?

Gracias.

Comment: *Quiero obtener el útlimo valor de la tabla* Para eso necesitas una consulta ordenada descendente o ascendentemente y que devuelva el TOP1. De hecho, se explica en la ayuda de [Dultimo](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funciones-dprim-dfirst-d%C3%BAltimo-dlast-adb06169-bf49-4f80-bf04-1e4b5a48a8a7)